# Nativescript - app not faster with webpacking

Tags: webpack, nativescript

Web-packed my app - for the Android and enabled snapshot + uglify (dev platform is mac).

Then added all my ui page files to the bundle file.

For the target architecture, set it to ARM only.

Here's how I'm creating the apk file:

`npm run build-android-bundle --snapshot --uglify -- --release <more-info>`

File size is a little bit smaller than without webpacking.

But no appreciable change in startup or execution times.

Any suggestions on what I should be looking for so that I'm taking full advantage of webpacking.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Webpack is not going to reduce the time your code takes to execute.

Comment: I expected the startup times to improve - NS guys did a whole bunch of webcasts about reducing time by about 70%.

Comment: Who are ns guys? What are these videos that promise 70% reduction of startup times?

Comment: If your bundle is massive, you can split it into multiple files and selectively load them as they are required. You can also use webpack with critical CSS to only load the styles that are needed for above-the-fold content (though I've not done this). These are just optimization for code loading though and won't increase the speed at which your code runs.

Comment: Nativescript doc site itself advertises that apps can decrease their startup times from 9 seconds to 2 and another of 5 to less than 2. https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/startup-times.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the nativescript tag, sorry. No idea about that.